# Style form elements in laravel stapler

Tags: html, css, laravel

In code I made this form element (I am using laravel stapler package) :

```
{{ Form::file('images', array('class' =>"btnUpload")) }}
```

This is an image of how this is shown in my browser and in developer tools :

[image]

I have given it a class but the styling I give is given to the surroundings not to the button `bestand kiezen` itself.

css code :

```
.btnUpload {
    padding : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    width 20%;
}

.btnUpload > button {
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
}
```

Comment: Surely `btn-succes` should be `btn-success`?

Comment: well that was only to test if bootstrap would fix this it has the same problem without that

Comment: Can you post the CSS for btnUpload that you are using. The fault lies in that code.

Comment: Edited to show my css code , but as you see I tried 2 things there just to test if it would work but the width is not at all changing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by declaring the form elements like this :

```
                {{Form::textarea('alt_description', null, array(
                    'id'      => 'pictureDescriptionInput',
                    'class'   => 'form-control',
                    'rows'    => 10,
                    'name'    => 'alt_description',
                    'placeholder' => 'Description',
                    'type'    => 'text'

                ));
                }}
```